# Unit test a class that uploads to S3

Tags: python, unit-testing, boto3

I've created a class that takes in a dataframe as an argument, converts it into a CSV file, and then puts it into a specified bucket in S3:

```
from io import StringIO
import boto3


class Push:
    def __init__(self, bucket):
        self.s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        self.bucket2 = bucket

    def push_to_cloud(self, df, folder):
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
        file_n = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
        file_name = file_n + ".csv"
        self.s3_resource.Object(self.bucket2, folder + "/" + file_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

How would I write a unittest to test whether the input is a data frame, and the output is a CSV?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) `boto3.resource`.
2. Run something like [Moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) if you want to test the actual HTTPS interaction; more suitable for functional tests.